# Обработка кнопки в view в alertdialog

Tags: java, android

Добрый день!

Только начинаю разбираться в android studio. Пытаюсь сделать диалог с кастомным view:

```
    public void dialogans(Activity activity, boolean cvet){              
            View view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.answer, null);                
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            adb.setView(view);        
        }
```

Никак не могу разобраться что писать в обработку нажатия кнопки чтоб диалог закрывался. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример(может и не самый лучший) при нажатии на кнопку "регистрация" всплывает диалог где нужно ввести поля:

```
    //кнопка с именем registration
        registration.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    //создание layout для диалога
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.teatcher_registration, null);
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    //здесь берем все EditText с layout teatcher_registration
                        final EditText log = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.login);
                        final EditText pas = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.password);
                        final EditText name = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                        final EditText lname = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.lastname);

                        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

    //если нажимаем ОК 

alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int ids) {

    //забираем текст
                                    String l = log.getText().toString();
                                    String p = pas.getText().toString();
                                    String n = name.getText().toString();
                                    String ln = lname.getText().toString();


                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                            });

                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                            alertDialog.show();
                        }
                }); 
             }
```